# Process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, process, streamwriter

I am trying to write the contents of an array (`temp`) to a new file should the array contain values.

However I receive this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll. The process cannot access the file (file path) because it is being used by another process.

I added `objwriter.Close()` to the end because I thought that perhaps it was still doing a process from the last time I ran the program, but the error still came up.

Code:

```
Dim filestoreorder As String = "filestoreorder.txt"
Dim objwriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("filestoreorder.txt")
For j = 0 To 30
   If temp(j) IsNot Nothing Then
       objwriter.Write(temp(j))
   End If
Next
'writes the out of stock products (in the temp array) into a new file (excluding null values)
objwriter.Close()
'closes the file
```

Comment: Do you have that file opened in say notepad or any other editor?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/1966/how-do-you-find-what-process-is-holding-a-file-open-in-windows) to see which process uses your file

Comment: No I don't have it opened elsewhere...

Comment: Reboot your machine just to clear this lock. Look into `Using objWriter As New StreamWriter("filestoreorder.txt")`. This will close _and_ dispose of the object.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely give that a go

Comment: Just for the record, it worked :)